# ipv6 with KVM on debian

Tags: networking, debian, kvm-virtualization, ipv6

I have trouble setting up IPV6 on my Proxmox (KVM) server:

My ISP sent me this information(xxx=placeholder):

```
IPs: 2a01:XXX:XXX:301:: /64
Gateway: 2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1 /59
```

This is the interface setup on the host server:

```
auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
    address  178.XX.XX.4
    broadcast 178.XX.XX.63
    netmask  255.255.255.192
    pointopoint 178.XX.XX.1
    gateway     178.XX.XX.1
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
iface vmbr1 inet6 static
    address 2a01:XXX:XXX:301::2
    netmask 64
    up ip -6 route add 2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1 dev vmbr1
    down ip -6 route del 2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1 dev vmbr1
    up ip -6 route add default via 2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1 dev vmbr1
    down ip -6 route del default via 2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1 dev vmbr1
```

On the guest:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 178.xx.xx.47
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    broadcast 178.xx.xx.63
    gateway 178.xx.xx.1
    pointopoint 178.xx.xx.1

iface eth0 inet6 static
    pre-up modprobe ipv6
    address 2a01:XXX:XXX:301::2:2
    netmask 64
        up ip -6 route add 2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1 dev eth0
        down ip -6 route del 2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1 dev eth0
        up ip -6 route add default via 2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1 dev eth0
        down ip -6 route del default via 2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1 dev eth0
```

Ipv4 works on both host and guest but Ipv6 only works "sometimes". It's up for minutes and then down again until I change something.

However I can actually ping the host and the guest from both host and guest.

```
host:~# ip -6 neigh
2a01:XXX:XXX:301::100:2 dev vmbr1 lladdr 00:50:56:00:00:e0 REACHABLE
2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1 dev vmbr1 lladdr 00:26:88:76:18:18 router STALE

host:~# ip -6 route
2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1 dev vmbr1  metric 1024  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
2a01:XXX:XXX:301::/64 dev vmbr1  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev vmbr0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev vmbr1  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
fe80::/64 dev tap101i1d0  proto kernel  metric 256  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
default via 2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1 dev vmbr1  metric 1024  mtu 1500 advmss 1440 hoplimit 4294967295
```

Does someone know why it isn't working? And is there a way to configure multiple v6 IPs from the same subnet so I can dedicate IPs to websites on a server with multiple virtualhosts?

Comment: Did you eventually get this to work? I have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I only have an answer for your second question.

In IPv6 you can have multiple IP address attached to the same interface. Unfortunately the debian tool for managing the network interfaces, [`ifupdown`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/ifupdown), is not able to manage multiple IPv6 address on one interface (see [this bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=168776) from 2002).

However, you can circumvent this problem by adding the extra IP address with a `up` directive. You can find several examples on various sites, like [this blog post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-linux-ipv6-virtual-additional-configuration/).

Answer (score 0):

If the host is the router for the guest, then you *must* install, configure and run radvd on the host. For this to work, *do not* filter/discard neighbor discovery packets. Otherwise the guest will not see a default route. You could also configure the default route manually, but that's tedious and error prone.

Addendum: don't forget to enable forwarding on the host and to allow for packet forwarding with ip6tables.

Answer (score -1):

i'd try to set it up the simplest way possible ...

For host:

```
iface vmbr1 inet6 static
    address 2a01:XXX:XXX:301::2
    netmask 59
    router 2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1
```

For guest:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
    pre-up modprobe ipv6
    address 2a01:XXX:XXX:301::2:2
    netmask 59
    router 2a01:XXX:XXX:300::1
```